# After enable winrm qc the host is not accessible using rdp windows

Tags: windows, winrm

I have one host. I was connected it using RDP Windows and then I just enable the winrm by using `winrm qc`

and then I logout from that host.

Now today when I was trying to access it it is not able to give permission to access it.

login failed invalid credentials.  But I am using same credentials.

Please help me

Comment: AFAIK, WinRM and RDP aren't related.  One is for viewing a remote desktop, the other is a remote management protocol for tools (like PowerShell, where I use it most).  Did you try logging on locally?  Is it a standalone host, part of a domain, joined to Azure, etc?

Comment: yes through remote desktop I was connecting it but after ran those winrm command and then logout yesterday night...now from today I am not able to login using remote desktop to that host to run some other commands..it is saying invalid credentials .....did winrm change the configuration/credentails??

Comment: It shouldn't change any usernames or passwords; from the Microsoft Docs: The winrm quickconfig command (or the abbreviated version winrm qc) performs these operations: 1) Starts the WinRM service, and sets the service startup type to auto-start 2) Configures a listener for the ports that send and receive WS-Management protocol messages using either HTTP or HTTPS on any IP address 3) Defines ICF exceptions for the WinRM service, and opens the ports for HTTP and HTTPS  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management

Comment: ok @DarkMoon .....